# C# WPF ComboBox - Exclude last row (or Blank Space) of Binding Data (binding from Microsoft Access)

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, combobox

Currently I am using Microsoft Access to keep the data and it will bind to WPF combobox. Below code was working almost fine.

```
oleDBCommand.CommandText =

"SELECT "
    + "table.[Col1] & ' - ' & table.[Col2] As COl1_Col2, table.[Col3] " +

"FROM "
    + "table_1 " +

"WHERE "
        + "(table_1.[col3] = '" + comboboxSelection.Text + "' OR table.[col3] = 'All') ";
```

The problem that I have is the combobox shows empty space in it. May I know how to remove it? Is it through Access Query or ComboBox Property?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try setting 
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
on your ComboBox.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this hides the invisible horizontal scroll bar but not the visible vertical bar?

Answer (score 0):

The combobox will only show the objects you give it, take a closer look at the data coming out of your query. You may need to add an additional filter in the where clause to exclude rows with empty values.

Comment: I do follow the step of guide (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584493/how-to-delete-the-blank-rows) and the blank space still remain. The only different was (compare to other combobox with using different table [that contain only 2 fields]), it have more then 8 fields. And I am not sure is the field could causing the blank space appear?

Comment: I find out that if my database row more then 15, it will show blank at the bottom of combobox. If my database row was 15 or less, it will not show any blank in the combobox.. Any one have idea on this?

Comment: Have you tested your query code in isolation from the WPF application to see if the query is returning a blank row of data?

Comment: I do test the query in Microsoft Access and it didn't show the blank row (last row as blank). One thing i found out that the blank row in WPF comboBox was not able to select. (mean it just appear there and when I try to select the blank row, it was not able to select)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old thread but I had the same issue with ComboBox. The thing is ComboBox align items to the TOP so it's not an extra item or line. It's just the space left after publishing your items. So let's say if your combobox height is 37 px and height of each item is 10px then you will see that last space of 7 px. Try keeping the height of combobox same as that of its individual elements.

```
 <ComboBox Width="200"
       Height="50"
       ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```